# Python issue: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found

Tags: python

I am trying to use the DeepChem library version 2.0.0 on a conda environment using python 2.7. I keep coming across this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_run_benchmark_models.py", line 30, in <module>
    seed=123)
  File "/home/ha01994/miniconda2/envs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/deepchem/molnet/run_benchmark.py", line 153, in run_benchmark
    featurizer=featurizer, reload=reload)
  File "/home/ha01994/miniconda2/envs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/deepchem/molnet/load_function/bace_datasets.py", line 80, in load_bace_classification
    save_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, "bace_c/" + featurizer + "/" + str(split))
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

This is the code around the line 80:

```
def load_bace_classification(featurizer='ECFP', split='random', reload=True):
    """Load bace datasets."""
    # Featurize bace dataset
    print("About to featurize bace dataset.")
    data_dir = deepchem.utils.get_data_dir()
    if reload:
        save_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, "bace_c/" + featurizer + "/" + str(split))

    dataset_file = os.path.join(data_dir, "bace.csv")

    if not os.path.exists(dataset_file):
        deepchem.utils.download_url('http://deepchem.io.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/datasets/bace.csv'
    )
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why are either `data_dir` or `featurizer` None?